# A proof regarding the order axiom, Can someone give me a hint?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**The Question**

Let $a,b,x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.

Given $a^2+b^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2=1$,

Prove: If $ax+by=1$ Then $a=x$ & $b=y$.

**Background & What i've tried to do**

I'm only allowed to use the properties of $\mathbb{R}$ as an ordered field.

The way i tried (Proof by contradiction)

Assume $a\not=x$ and $b\not=y$ , According to the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is an ordered field, There must be an order between $x,a$ and $b,y$ (Trichotomy).

Assume $a>x$ and $b>y$

If $a^2+b^2=1$ then $x^2+y^2<1$, Thats a contradition. (Same for the $x>a$ and $y>b$ case)

**My problem**

Assume $a>x$ and $b<y$

I can't really figure out how to use $ax+by$ to conclude a contradiction. Can you hint me on how to do this?

Thank you very much, It is my first time asking in Math.Exchange.

**P.S:**

If anyone has any tips on how to get better at writing & solving proofs (Good books, videos etc), I would love that too. (Starting a Math B.Sc in October).

Comment: The vectors $(a,b)$ and $(x,y)$ both have length $1$, and their dot product is $1$. What does that tell you about the angle between them?

Comment: A friend of mine hinted me on this solution, But I'm only allowed to use the order axiom and its properties for this practice problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that$$(a-x)^2+(b-y)^2=a^2+b^2+x^2+y^2-2(ax+by)=1+1-2=0.$$This uses nothing but order axioms and the fact that squares are non-negative (which is an immediate consequence of those axioms).

Comment: @Dvir: This is one of those things where the choice of the first thing seems completely magical, but it's not: you want to show that $a = x$ and $b = y$, which is like saying that $a-x = 0$ and $b-y = 0$. Now $(a-x)^2$ is zero *only* if $a = x$, and is positive otherwise; same for $(b-y)^2$. So their sum is zero only if *both* are zero. So this sum is something reasonable to look at. As an alternative, if you drew a little arrow from $(a, b) $ to $(x,y)$ in the plane, the squared length of that arrow would be exactly $(a-x)^2 + (b-y)^2$, so showing it's zero shows the two points are the same.

Comment: Thank you both a lot for this!